# Android - How to convert KeyEvent KeyCode to Char?

Tags: android

I want to get the char value of the KeyCode Event when pressing an Android keyboard.

```
public void KeyCodeEventAsChar(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

  char pressedKey;

  // TODO: convert key Code Event into char

  syslog.d ("TEST", "The pressed key in Android keyboard was char: " + pressedKey);

}
```

Does anyone has a clue how to do this?!

**UPDATE:**

I don't want hardcoded text! I want to convert it to correspondent char!

**UPDATE 2:**

I need also to dead chars such as: à, á, ò, ó, etc...

**ANSWER FOUND:**

```
// TODO: convert key Code Event into char
char pressedKey = (char) event.getUnicodeChar();
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** char has only 1 byte length, so it will **not** support several chars

Comment: in Java `char` is UTF-16, so it can keep all the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)

Answer (score 12):

**> I had already answered updating the question**

```
// TODO: convert key Code Event into char
char pressedKey = (char) event.getUnicodeChar();
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE: char has only 1 byte length, so it will not support several chars**

Hope it help you somehow

Comment: just a note: in java char has 2 bytes

Answer (score 4):

In order to test the **Answer Found** you can do this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    char pressedKey = (char) event.getUnicodeChar();

    Log.d("onKeyUp is: ", Character.toString(pressedKey));


    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);

}
```

And the letter that you pressed should appear in the `logcat`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [KeyEvent.getDisplayLabel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getDisplayLabel%28%29) to get the primary character for the key. In other words, the label that is physically printed on it.

Comment: I need also to dead chars such as: à, á, ò, ó, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You have to check which key is getting pressed like this

```
if(keyCode  == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

syslog.d ("TEST", "The pressed key in Android keyboard was Enter" );
}
```

Here is the link where you find all the KeyEvents

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: @SachinGurnami I don't want that hardcoded. For int event=KeyEvent.KEYCODE_G, i can translate that to "G"!

Comment: then use keyEvent.getUnicodeChar();

Answer (score 0):

```
KEYCODE_XX is an int
```

You can have a method that has keycode as parameter and use switch case in it to do specifc 
task. like below,

```
void getEvent(KeyEvent keyEvent){

    char pressedKey = (char) keyEvent.getUnicodeChar();

    switch(pressedKey){
        case A://
        syslog.d ("TEST", "The pressed key in Android keyboard was Enter" );
        //DO what you wnat with this event
        break;
        case B:
        syslog.d ("TEST", "The pressed key in Android keyboard was B" );
        //DO what you wnat with this event
        break;
        // so on to check other keys
    }
}
```

This way you can use Unicode to get corresponding values and you can use this with key listener to get events continuously

Comment: @Vincent... I don't want that hardcoded. For int event=KeyEvent.KEYCODE_G, i can translate that to "G"!